# Fitting data with inclusion of constraints

Tags: numerics, fitting, data, modeling

How do I  find a fit for the dataS (see below) with the constraint that the parameter np
is an integer, and that the parameters la+lc = 100. A weak attempt at this is provided below for a specific model.

```
Clear[dataS, np, th, lc, la, sc, sa, q]

dataS = {{0.0200243, 8.51113}, {0.0223801, 7.38727}, {0.0247359, 6.49431}, {0.0270917, 5.78094}, {0.0294475, 5.24383}, {0.0318033, 4.85481}, {0.0341591, 4.58093}, {0.0365148, 4.38386}, {0.0388706, 4.26912}, {0.0412264, 4.19256}, {0.0435821, 4.1748}, {0.0459379, 4.14528}, {0.0482937, 4.10548}, {0.0506494, 4.01107}, {0.0530051, 3.82845}, {0.0553609, 3.54445}, {0.0577166, 3.1787},  {0.0600723, 2.74405}, {0.062428, 2.29171}, {0.0647837, 1.8642}, {0.0671394, 1.48718}, {0.0694951, 1.16843}, {0.0718508, 0.927279}, {0.0742065, 0.735171}, {0.0765621, 0.588362}, {0.0789178, 0.476123}, {0.0812734, 0.388092}, {0.083629, 0.319444}, {0.0859847, 0.264057}, {0.0883403, 0.220424}, {0.0906959, 0.184743}, {0.0930515, 0.155816}, {0.0954071, 0.132327}, {0.0977626, 0.113781}, {0.100118, 0.0978715}, {0.102474, 0.0844484}, {0.104829, 0.0736506}, {0.107185, 0.0651143}, {0.10954, 0.057349}}; 

Fc[q_, lc_, sc_] := Exp[I*lc*q]*Exp[-0.5*sc^2*q^2]; 
Fa[q_, la_, sa_] := Exp[I*la*q]*Exp[-0.5*sa^2*q^2]; 
ModelP = (2/q^4)*Re[((1 - Fc[q, lc, sc])*(1 - Fa[q, la, sa]))/(1 - Fc[q, lc, sc]*Fa[q, la, sa]) + (1/np)*((Fa[q, la, sa]*(1 - Fc[q, lc, sc])^2)/(1 - Fc[q, lc, sc]*Fa[q, la, sa])^2)*
       (1 - Fc[q, lc, sc]*Fa[q, la, sa])^np]; 
f1 = FindFit[dataS, {ModelP, {4 < np < 50, 10 < la < 30, 60 < lc < 100, 1 < sa < 40, 1 < sc < 40}}, {np, la, lc, sa, sc}, q]
```

Output: {np -> 9.66343, la -> 14.9484, lc -> 63.5122, sa -> 23.7186, 
 sc -> 2.7161}

Comment: It is good to note that your use of N as a variable is a no-no. N is a built-in function. There are a few more single letter reserved symbols (C, D, E, I, O), so it's best to avoid all capitalized variable names (you can use capitalization using [lower camel case](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LowerCamelCase), though). That way you avoid any conflict with built-in functions that are *always* capitalized.

Comment: @ Sjoerd Agree, have changed N to Np

Comment: Well, actually I was suggesting not to capitalize the first letter of a symbol name. So, although `Np` is slightly better I'd advise against it.

Comment: @ Sjoerd changed Np to np

Answer (score 4):

The requirement that `la + lc == 100` is simple to implement, just pass `100 - la` to `Fc`, or use

```
ModelP/.{lc->100-la}
```

in the call to `FindFit`.

For the other trouble, remember that `N` is a special function in Mathematica, so avoid ever using this as a variable. Using `n` instead, I tried

```
ModelP = (2/q^4)*Re[((1 - Fc[q, lc, sc])*(1 - Fa[q, la, sa]))/
(1 - Fc[q, lc, sc]*Fa[q, la, sa]) +
(1/n)*((Fa[q, la, sa]*(1 - Fc[q, lc, sc])^2)/
(1 - Fc[q, lc, sc]*Fa[q, la, sa])^2)*(1 - Fc[q, lc, sc]*Fa[q, la, sa])^n];

f1 = FindFit[
dataS, {ModelP /. {lc -> 100 - la}, {4 < n < 50, 10 < la < 30, 
1 < sa < 40, 1 < sc < 40, n \[Element] Integers}}, {n, la, lc, sa,
sc}, q]
```

but I get the error message:

> "Constraints in {n[Element]Integers,1 < sa,1 < sc,4 < n,10 < la,la <
>   30,n < 50,sa < 40,sc < 40} are not all equality or inequality
>   constraints. With the exception of integer domain constraints for
>   linear programming, domain constraints or constraints with Unequal
>   (!=) are not supported."

A workaround could be to make the model a function of `n`, and then run `FindFit` for several integer values of `n` and compare the results.

Comment: Still unable to use the above input to get anywhere close to the answer, useful nevertheless. If I remove (4 < n < 50) the error message disappears.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. If you want to test that range (4 < n < 50) then do `f1 = Table[FindFit[
dataS, {ModelP /. {lc -> 100 - la,n -> i}, {10 < la < 30, 
1 < sa < 40, 1 < sc < 40}}, {la, lc, sa,
sc}, q], {i, 5, 49} ]`. Then you can compare the results for different `n`.